# Generating ETAG using spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, etag

I'm new to spring boot.
I want to generate ETAG whenever perform a POST from my controller class.

Below is the configuration class created:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Filter shallowEtagHeaderFilter() {
        return new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter();
    }
}
```

My main class is annotated with `@EnableAutoConfiguration`.
As per my understanding, the response object that I receive from POST should provide me the ETAG header.
Please can anyone provide a spring boot sample to generate ETag during my POST/GET?PUT call.

Answer (score 3):

The `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter`you are using will only generate an ETag in response to a `GET` request.

When you perform a `GET` on the resource you just created/updated, the ETag header will be present.

It is also worth nothing that if you are making use of the Spring Repository REST exporter (i.e. Spring Data Rest), then it has ETag support built in. All that is required is for your entity classes to have a `Long` or `Timestamp` field annotated with `@javax.persistence.Version`

Comment: So is that means while I do PUT or POST or DELETE, I am forced to set ETag in the request header?

Comment: Yes, you have to send the ETag value in the request in the 'If-Match' header. The server will reject the request if the ETag does not match.

Comment: @adamp it didn't work for me, got Etag(123) from GET, used If-Match=123 in header for PUT and executed it, and repeated same step - If-Match=123 in header for PUT and executed it. It worked, i presume it shouldn't work. Etag would have changed it once first PUT has happened. For 2nd PUT it is supposed to throw error, but it didn't. I am also using Long variable in Entity javax.persistence.Version.

Comment: hi @kumar, did you check after your first PUT to see if the Etag incremented to 124?

Comment: @Version is not incrementing value at all, it always remain same, even after multiple PUT operations by changing data.

Comment: @kumar If the version field is not incrementing then this is another issue. Can you verify that the PUT was successful and the entity has been updated (and can be seen in your subsequent GET? Is there any caching going on?

Comment: Yes PUT is updating DB record, GET is fetching me updated record.